# How to convert point data to polygon data

Tags: r, shiny, gis, r-sf

I would like to know how to convert point data to polygon data.
I have the following csv file.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1qEa7nCThg5lyC2glXOhKCspNzeBRf0IH/view?usp=sharing

This was processed as follows.

```
df <- read.csv("sample.csv")%>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon","lat"),crs = 4612)
```

However, this alone makes it a point type. I want to convert to polygon type from here.
What kind of processing should I do?

If you know the specific method, or please let me know the web page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in *combining* the point features and *casting* into a polygon feature, using `sf` you could run the following:

```r
df <- read.csv("sample.csv") %>%
      st_as_sf(coords = c("lon","lat"), crs = 4612) %>%
      st_combine() %>%   # combine POINT features into a single MULTIPOINT feature
      st_cast("POLYGON") # Cast to POLYGON feature
```

This would give you a polygon feature that looks like this:

[image: polygon]